# list new activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [list new list activty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276242/list-new-list-activty)

I want to start new Different activty when I press on any row of the list. Can any one give me an example on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xjaphx code for listview. if you are using Custom adapter for your listview thn you can use below code..

```
      listview.setAdapter(new customeAdapter(this));
```

Class for CustomAdapter as follows

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;

    CustomAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context=context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {         
        return 5;//size of listview
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {

        ViewContainer holder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(context);
     if (view == null) 
     {

         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfeedlist, null);
        holder = new ViewContainer();
        holder.feedTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

        holder.arrow=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.arrow_imageview);
        view.setTag(holder);
     }
     else
     {
         holder = (ViewContainer) view.getTag();
     }
         holder.feedTitle.setText(mylist.get(position));
         holder.feedTitle.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);


         holder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);

         view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v)
             {
                 Intent intent=new Intent(currentclass.this,DifferentActivity.class);

                 startActivity(intent);
                 finish(); 

             }
         });

     return view;
    }

}

   class    ViewContainer
  {
TextView feedTitle;
ImageView arrow;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public class MainAcitvity {
    ListView mList = null;

    public void onCreate() {

        // load list view
        mList = (ListView) findViewById(....);

        // set whatever data and adapter..
        mList.setAdapter(...);

        // set a item click
        mList.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DifferentActivity.class) // set your Different activity class here
                MainActivity.startActivity(i);
            }   
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple different activities, make sure you figure out which activity to start.

My example is going off of the assumption that the list view order does not change.

```
Context mContext = this;
...

public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  if(id == 0) {
    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Activity0.class));
  } else if (id == 1) {
    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Activity1.class));
  }
}
```

and so on for each different activity.

Note you only need one line for starting an Activity, saves type time and minuscule amounts of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the swith(){} to achieve.