# Show New List from ListActivity's Item Click Event

Tags: android, list, listview, arraylist, android-listview

```
package com.comboyz.TantaGo;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; 

public class startMenu extends ListActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter <String>(this,R.layout.startmenu,category));
    }
    static final String [] category= new String []{
        "cinema","restuarnt","hotel","cafe","women shoping","men shoping"
    };
}
```

i want when i click on `cinema` make a new list have all names of cinema & when i press resturant it make different list have all names of the resturant and so on

Comment: do you mean with having a new list? removing the old?

Comment: meen it get me to anther list have all names of the cinema

Comment: why don't you write another activity and pass the KeyWord (Cinema/Restaurant) to it using Intent Extras...and like above make new list and show there accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this, however I recommend doing a few changes.

First off, use a ListView element, apposed to doing ListActivity, check out [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-example) example.

Then I would suggest playing around with ViewFlipper, you can set animations to flip between the different view elements, how they work is they have a hierarchy of view elements, which can only show one at a time, so what you would do is, for example,

```
<ViewFlipper
      .... >

    <ListView
         ... >

    <ListView
         ... >

    <ListView
         ... >

</ViewFlipper>
```

When you get the View Flipper in your main Activity, you will set the displayed view, and as you set 0,1,2 it will flip between the list views, for example 0 could be main screen, 1 theaters, 2 restaurants, etc

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can use context menu for your list, but it just fired for long click event. For example:

```
  registerForContextMenu(listView);
```

Ref http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/contextmenu-for-listview-longclick-event-in-android-t2034.html